# Excel calculate time difference

Tags: excel, time, difference

Is there any way (I can't find it anywhere) to calculate the time difference (in minutes) when I have this format of time in a single cell:

Example:

| A (start time-end time / start time-end time) | B (sum of time difference in minutes) |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00-06:00 / 22:00-24:00 | 480 |

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  On what type of machine? Also what type of answer are you looking for: formula, vba, or other?

Comment: It is Excel 2016, Windows 10, 64. I'm looking only for formula.. I got something and it's works: =SUM(TEXT((MID(A5;7;5))-(LEFT(A5;5));"[mm]");TEXT((RIGHT(A5;5))-(MID(A5;15;5));"[mm]"))   BUT!  If I enter only one part of time like 22:00-24:00 (which also possible in this my table) i've got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use FILTERXML to return an array of the times and subtract the 1 and 3 position from the 2 and 4 position respectively.

Wrap in IFERROR to deal with there not being a second time inputted.

Then sum:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","-"),"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s["&{2,4}&"]")-FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","-"),"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s["&{1,3}&"]"),0))*24*60
```

**Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode**

[image]

Note: FILTERXML is only available on later versions of Excel and not available on Mac versions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! But I found that this works fine for me:

```
=IFERROR(IF((LEN(C5)=25);SUM(TEXT((MID(C5;7;5))-(LEFT(C5;5));"[mm]");TEXT((RIGHT(C5;5))-(MID(C5;15;5));"[mm]"));SUM(TEXT((MID(C5;7;5))-(LEFT(C5;5));"[mm]")));"")
```